# kn: Recycle instance if running for more than 30 days

Tags: knative

How do I configure knative yaml for this scneario:

1. Application has minScale=1, maxScale=1
2. If application is running > x days, recycle this instance; i.e create another instance, route all traffic to it, and kill current, so endstate remains minScale=1.

Edit:

Looks like at present, users need to rely on a master-switch k8s 'Descheduler'. However if folks in kn world add this feature for app/service/pod specific. Will need to update this edit.

Answer (score 2):

Knative Serving does not support such a policy as of today. However, the community thinks that Kubernetes' Descheduler should work just fine, as is discussed in https://github.com/knative/serving/issues/6176.

Comment: Thanks for the info - reading through the issue gives more insight. I'll try to upvote that issue, so the 'feature' becomes prooritized :-). Will try descheduler -- but 'descheduler' it seems to be a global master switch rather than app specific.

Comment: Descheduler can operate on specific pod labels, so you could key off the existence of `serving.knative.dev/revision` label, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Not kn specific but you could try adding `activeDeadlineSeconds` to the podSpec.